# java cannot find symbol error: beginner

Tags: java, methods, static, symbols

When compiled this static method comes up with the error that the int array variable, coord, cannot be found. I declared it within the method and it is of the type int[] and I can't figure out why it won't work. I have a feeling that it has to do with the method being static, but changing it to static was the only way I found to make that method work in the first place.

I feel like this is probably really simple for anybody but me especially when all I could find on this subject were much more complicated coding issues.

In case this helps.. this method is supposed to return the (x,y) coordinates for a move location. Sorry for probably not inputting the code correctly. First time doing this. Thanks in advance for any help

CODE:

```
public static int[] getMove(String player)
{
    boolean done = false;
    while(!done)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input row for " + player);
        int x = in.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println("Input column for " + player);
        int y = in.nextInt() - 1;
        int[] coord = {x,y};
        if(getLoc(coord[0], coord[1]).equals("x") || getLoc(coord[0], coord[1]).equals("o") || coord[0] < 0 || coord[0] > ROWS || coord[1] < 0 || coord[1] > COLUMNS)

        {
            System.out.println("Invalid coordinates... please retry");
        }
        else
        {
            done = true;
        }
    } 
    return coord;   
}
```

Comment: coord are declared in while loop .............if u want to return coord by ur method please declare above the while loop...

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is the *scope* of the variable. A variable declared in parent block is accessible in child blocks, but not the other way around.

```
public void someMethod()
{
int x=1;

while(x<10)
{
x++; //x is accessible here, as it is defined in parent block.
int j = 0; //This variable is local to while loop and will cause error if used inside method
j++;
}
System.out.println(j);// The outer block does not know about the variable j!!
}
```

Now in your case,

- Notice where you have defined coors, and in what all places you are using it.
- Try to figure where should you *define* coors variable.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the array `coord` is local to the `while` loop. And therefore its not visible outside its scope. Move the declaration of `coord` outside the `while` and it should work.

```
int[] coord = new int[2];
while(!done){
    ...
    ...
    coord[0] = x;
    coord[1] = y;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple like that.